# xAPI doesn't always send launch statements

Tags: tin-can-api

I have a small application with two pages. After the login page, the first page is a table of contents with a list of videos from which the user can select a youtube video of their choice. When the user selects a video from the sidebar menu they are taken to the page where the video plays and I have included it in the code below. This app uses the xAPI Youtube Video Tracking - ADL on Github and it basically does as advertised sending any number of kinds of statements like launch, suspend, resume and completed. The issue though, is that it doesn't always send "launch" statements. For example, if I preview a video and decide that it is one that I want, I'll code it in. Then if I log in as John Doe and play it the first statement is "resume." Is this because I've previewed the video on my own and youtube somehow remembers this? Is there something with my code below that is causing this? If I code a youtube video in without previewing it, it seems to send a launch statement as one would expect it to. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Play Video</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--optional logo-->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/justSyniverse.png" width="169" height="43"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="list-group"> 

        <a href="tableOfContents.html" class="list-group-item active">
            <i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Table of Contents
        </a>


        <!--************** Ansible *************-->
        <!--***** Parent button ******-->
        <a href="#ansible" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-group"></i> Ansible
            <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
        </a>

        <div id="ansible" class="list-group subitem collapse">    

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=What Is Ansible%3F&emCode=xMHVvHZ-Zn4" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> What is Ansible?
                <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Getting Started&emCode=In9XI-3ByQ8" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Getting Started
            </a>


            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Concepts Explained&emCode=2jXHxkLBOHg" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Concepts Explained
            </a>

        </div>
        <!--************** end Ansible ************-->



        <!--************** Chef *************-->
        <!--***** Parent button ******-->
        <a href="#chef" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-group"></i> Chef
            <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
        </a>

        <div id="chef" class="list-group subitem collapse">    

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Overview of Chef&emCode=yh9osPQA_-k" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Overview of Chef
                <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Install Chef&emCode=r3mN2M9n51Y" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Install Chef
            </a>

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Setup a node %26 write to a cookbook&emCode=71Cq4bCxgDk" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Setup a node & write to a cookbook
            </a>

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Client Run %26 expanding the cookbook&emCode=H3Ggublb378" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Client Run & expanding the cookbook
            </a>

        </div>
        <!--************** end Chef ************-->





        <!--************** Docker ************-->
        <!--***** Parent button ******-->
        <a href="#docker" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-group"></i> Docker
            <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
        </a>

        <div id="docker" class="list-group subitem collapse"> 

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=What Is Docker%3F&emCode=t9YuqwGYUUg" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> What is Docker?
                <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="playVideoPage.html?Title=Run a %27hello world%27 container&emCode=JBODRMslzAU" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Run a 'Hello World' container
                <span class="badge bg_danger"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
        <!--************** end Docker ************-->

        <!--Logout-->
        <a href="#" id="logout" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Logout
        </a>




    </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->


        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 id="myMainTitle">Video Plays here</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum... </p>
                        <!--<p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>-->
                        <!--<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>-->
                        <div id="player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/xapiwrapper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/xapi-youtube-statements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/videoprofile.js"></script>

  <script>

  <!--This pulls the variables from the url query string-->
  var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();



  <!--This creates a var from the youtube embed code-->
  var video = urlParams["emCode"];
  <!--This creates a variable of the actual youtube title-->
  var videoTitle = urlParams["Title"];
  $("#myMainTitle").text(videoTitle);

  <!--We have to pull the global variables from localStorage-->
    var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var email = localStorage.getItem('email');

    //var mEmail = email;
//  var personName = name;

    // "global" variables read by ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.changeConfig({
      "actor":  {"mbox":"mailto:" + email, "name":name},
      "videoActivity": {"id":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video, "definition":{"name": {"en-US":videoTitle}} }
    });

    function initYT() {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: video,
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0 },
        events: {
          'onReady': ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    initYT();


    // Auth for the LRS
    var conf = {
        "endpoint" : "https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/",
        "auth" : "Basic " + toBase64("xapi-tools:xapi-tools"),
    };

    ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig(conf);

    /*
     * Custom Callbacks
     */
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onPlayerReadyCallback = function(stmt) {
      console.log("on ready callback");
    }

    // Dispatch Youtube statements with XAPIWrapper
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onStateChangeCallback = function(event, stmt) {
      console.log(stmt);
      if (stmt) {
        stmt['timestamp'] = (new Date()).toISOString();
        ADL.XAPIWrapper.sendStatement(stmt, function(){});
      } else {
        console.warn("no statement found in callback for event: " + event);
      }
    }

  </script>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/init.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really see anywhere in this code or the linked in libraries that a `launched` statement would ever be generated. Can you narrow that down?

Comment: Somehow or another the xAPI youtube video tracking app does it. It sends statements when I launch, suspend, resume and complete a video. 
Update: I kept experimenting with this and if I am logged out of google/youtube and get the video specifics first then try the app, it does send a launch statement. Bottom line seems to be if you look at a video to see if that is the one that you want, youtube remembers this, then when I test it with my app it does not send a launch b/c it remembers that I already launched it. I know this is confusing but I believe that I understand what is going on now. TY